# ViewPager's Third Fragment is not storing HashMap in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, hashmap, android-viewpager

I'm facing strange issue i have a `ViewPager` with **three fragments**.
In all of these three fragments i'm passing my **image** object in bundle as.

```
 public static InfoFragment newInstance(Image image,String path) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("object",image);//passing my image object 
        args.putString("path",path);
        InfoFragment fragment = new InfoFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and then retrieving this in onCreate. In **onCreate** image object is retrieved successfully but when i try to access this in **onCreateView** the image object only has id and title.The  `tags` become null. 
My Image class is something like this

```
public class Image implements Parcalable{
     private String id;
     private String title;
     private HashMap<String,String> tags;

     //getters/setters
     //parcalable things 
}
```

**Note:**
This strange behaviour is happening just in third fragment of **ViewPager** in first two fragments everything is working fine.

Screenshots: **First Fragment**
[image: First Fragment]

**Third Fragment**
[image: Third Fragment]

Comment: Have you tried setting .setOffscreenPageLimit() ? If rasing the number of Fragment being created immediately also resolves your null object, than it is obviously lifecycle problem...

Comment: i have total 3 fragments and yes i already have tried setOffScreenPageLimit(3).

Comment: @Gotiasits i have attached the screenshots of my viewpager.

Comment: Very interesting. And have you tried switching the order of the fragments in `getItem()` to make sure its always the third fragment, and not that specific instance?
BTW, I had similar requirements, and I used Singleton, controlled by Fragment instances.

Comment: @Gotiasits yes i have tried it it always give this issue in third fragment. The more intresting i have debug the program it is retriving the value in onCreate and store as a part of Image object but when it comes to onCreateView the Image object lose the hashmap object and still have other fields like id and title.

Answer (score 0):

There is other solution to achieve this as create a constant static final variable of HashMap and access or update this HasMap from any where.

```
public static final HashMap<String,String> variableName;
```